# What package do I install to use Oxygen in Qt4?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, themes, appearance, qt

When you install some qt apps in ubuntu like smplayer and lyx, you can change their appearance eiher with their preferences menu or with the qt-config utility. You can choose between several themes like motif, gtk+ or plastique but you can't choose the oxygen style unless you have installed some kde packages and i'm not sure if you have to install the whole kde desktop. Does anyone know which package i have to install to select the oxygen theme for qt4 apps?

Summary: What i intend to do is to set the oxygen theme to qt apps in gnome, but without changing gnome apps using oxygen-molecule or another theme

Comment: @fossfreedom: not exactly, i'm trying something different, qt4 apps in gnome using the oxygen theme, but without using oxygen-molecule or another gtk theme for gnome apps

Comment: ok - please add your clarification comment into your question.

Answer (score 2):

with the release of kde SC 4.8 now you can install the oxygen style to use with qt or kde apps without installing the whole kde base, you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install kde-style-oxygen
```

You need to add the kubuntu backport repository to get the last version of kde.

The above steps works for an ubuntu 11.10 installation. Still searching if it is possible to install kde 4.8 in ubuntu 11.04